# How to implement darkmode in stencil.js using tailwind and test it on storybook?

Tags: ionic-framework, storybook, stenciljs, darkmode

I have tried using these two methods.
**1. Using storybook tailwind dark mode add-on**.
https://corechasm.com/addons/@jhaynie/storybook-tailwind-dark-mode
**2. Using storybook config.**
https://workingconcept.com/blog/storybook-components-dark-mode

Note: Dark mode works when I turn it on from the system setting of the windows. (personalization app mode in default to dark)

get to know how to configure dark mode in stencil.js and storybook with tailwindcss.